# Weird behavior of new figures in MATLAB

Tags: oop, matlab, user-interface

I have created a class-managed GUI in which the following methods are defined

```
function h = make_figure(this)
    h = figure('CloseRequestFcn',@this.close_figure);
    this.openFigures(end+1) = h;
end

function close_figure(this, src, event)
    this.openFigures(this.openFigures == src) = [];
    delete(src);
end
```

Throughout the life of the GUI maney figures are created and closed with the aid of the methods above. Now the weird part...

If I double click a figure file eg (myfigure.fig) in MATLAB's "Current Folder" window and then try to close it (while the GUI is still alive) then the `close_figure` method of the GUI's class runs although it wasn't created with `h = figure('CloseRequestFcn',@this.close_figure);` of `make_figure` method!!! This is the first weird part. The second weird part is that, although an unintented part of code is executed, it shouldn't create problems because the command `this.openFigures(this.openFigures == src) = [];` actually leaves `this.openFigures` unchanged and practically all that `close_figure` does is to `delete(src)` which is desirable. Despite the above, my program behaves... weird after the above happens.

I have noticed that if I hit `figure` in the command window and then close it, everything is OK, the `close_figure` method is not executed. The problem reveals itself only when opening a .fig file created by the GUI's class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the scenario you described, and I am not seeing any weird behavior; create instance of the class, use it to make a figure, then open a FIG file from the "Current Folder" file browser, and close it..

Here is the class definition I used:

```
classdef MyFigureClass < handle
    properties
        openFigures = [];
    end

    methods
        function h = make_figure(obj)
            h = figure('CloseRequestFcn',@(src,evt) close_figure(obj,src,evt));
            obj.openFigures(end+1) = h;
        end

        function close_figure(obj, src, evt)
            obj.openFigures(obj.openFigures == src) = [];
            delete(src);
        end

    end
end
```

*(Tested in R2012a on Windows XP 32-bit.)*

---

#### EDIT

Ok I think I know what the problem is. Here are the step to reproduce. First add the following method to the class above:

```
function save_figure(obj, idx)
    saveas(obj.openFigures(idx), sprintf('fig%02d.fig',idx))
end
```

Now using our class wrapper, lets create a figure, and save it to FIG file:

```
f = MyFigureClass();
f.make_figure()
f.save_figure(1)       %# creates fig01.fig
```

Next clear your workspace `clear all`, and move the class definition file `MyFigureClass.m` to some other folder (something not on the path). Now try to load the saved figure `hgload fig01.fig`, and it will throw the error:

```
Warning: Cannot load an object of class 'MyFigureClass':
Its class cannot be found. 
> In C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\graphics\hgload.p>localLoadFile at 167
  In C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\graphics\hgload.p>hgload at 59
  In openfig at 72
  In open at 159
  In uiopen at 196
```

You will have to issue the following command to forcefully close it:

```
close all force
```

---

#### EDIT2

One solution (as mentioned in the comments), is to [reset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#CloseRequestFcn) the figure close callback function just before saving it. Here is how I modified the `save_figure` function above:

```
function save_figure(obj, idx)
    %# backup callback function
    fcn = get(obj.openFigures(idx),'CloseRequestFcn');

    %# set default callback function
    set(obj.openFigures(idx),'CloseRequestFcn','closereq')

    %# save figure
    saveas(obj.openFigures(idx), sprintf('fig%02d.fig',idx))

    %# restore callback function
    set(obj.openFigures(idx),'CloseRequestFcn',fcn)
end
```

Comment: what exactly is in the FIG file you are opening? is it a GUIDE-generated GUI, or simply a MATLAB figure you saved? Either way, create a fresh one (nothing fancy just very simple one), and try again... If problem still persists, I suspect that your installation may be broken somehow, and advise you to reinstall

Comment: @niels: Oh, the issue is that when saved the figure from inside the class, it created a closure (for the callback function). Now in a new session, if you try to open the FIG file, and the class definition file is not on the MATLAB path, it will throw the error you mentioned..

Comment: @niels: I added steps to reproduce the error... Now obviously the solution is to keep both the class definition and the saved FIG files together (and make it available on the path)

Comment: @niels: I added a solution which reset the callback function to MATLAB's default just before saving the figure, and restores it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out that there is a related issue here that others may face.  You should NOT open your GUI by double clicking the gui.fig file.  This is not the desired behavior because your opening function will never be called.  Should you have code in there as many of us do it will not execute, another side effect is that the handles variable will also not be set properly.

What you SHOULD do is either open it in GUIDE first then click run, or run the gui.m file directly.  That will yield the desired results and the gui will function as intended.